Rulings Regarding Toughness and Modifiers
My question is about how power and toughness modifiers work when regarding abilities that reference stats. In particular the scenario I encountered was a Loxodon Punisher with a +2 Mace and a Sandsteppe Mastodon. The modified toughness of the Punisher was a 6, does the Mastodon’s ability apply to it which has a toughness of 5 or the punisher who has a base toughness of 2?

Mastodon's ability will consider Loxodon to have 6 toughness, not 2.

110.3. A nontoken permanent's characteristics are the same as those printed on its card, as modified by any continuous effects.

When a card interacts with base toughness, it will specifically say so. For example, Angelic Aberration's ability:

When Angelic Aberration enters, sacrifice any number of creatures each with base power or toughness 1 or less. Create that many 4/4 colorless Eldrazi Angel creature tokens with flying and vigilance.

